# Capture cpu utilization and memory utilization from the oracle autonomous database using query

Tags: oracle, datadog, oracle-autonomous-db, datadog-dashboard

I'm looking to calculate free space, used space, and allocated storage as percentages for our Oracle Autonomous Database (ADB). Additionally, I'd like to set up an alert in Datadog to notify us when the database storage reaches 80% capacity. Could you please provide guidance on how to capture these metrics in Datadog and set up the alert? Thank you!

I am looking for a custom query that i need to integrate with datadog

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you connect to the OCI Monitoring service, to the autonomous database namespace and then fetch these metrics:

- StorageAllocated
- StorageUsed
- StorageUtilization

These are available for both ADB deployment types and it's a nice way to not bother the database with connections and queries (as the metrics are automatically being collected in the OCI Monitoring service).